# Remove specific, non-html tags from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'd like to know how I can easily remove specific values from a string using C# and RegEx. I have the following HTML string:

```
Add [tt]PEELED PLUM SHAPED TOMATOES in tomato juice[/tt][rg]WHOLE PEELED TOMATOES[/rg][rp]WHOLE   PEELED TOMATOES in JUICE[/rp], basil, oregano, parsley, salt, black pepper, sugar, [tt]TOMATO SAUCE[/tt][rg]TOMATO SAUCE[/rg][rp]TOMATO SAUCE[/rp], [brand][rg]TOMATO PASTE[/rg][rp]TOMATO PASTE[/rp]
```

I need some way to filter out e.g. this part:

```
[tt]PEELED PLUM SHAPED TOMATOES in tomato juice[/tt]
```

So the [tt] tag should be removed as well as the text that is in between. If the [tt] tag occurs multiple times inside the source string, it should be removed as well.

It this doable by using RegEx?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As long as the `[tt]` tags are never nested, it's easy:

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, @"\[tt\].*?\[/tt\]", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

If you do expect nested `[tt]` tags, then you need to apply the following command repeatedly, once for each level of nesting:

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, @"\[tt\](?:(?!\[/?tt\]).)*\[/tt\]", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: ...but what happens when the string looks like `[tt]abc[tt]def[/tt]ghi[/tt]`?? Oh thats right. Don't use regex to parse html.

Comment: If you're worried about nesting, it's easy enough to throw it into a loop and replace until there are no more matches.

Comment: @Lincoded: No, that wouldn't work with this regex. It would match `[tt] foo [tt] bar [/tt]`. It *can*  be changed to handle that, though.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say that the exact regex mentioned above would work for nesting, but you're definitely right about that.